# Select data using VARBINARY in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `mytable` that contains a row with the following data:

`uid: 1 (type: int(10))`

`email: it is visible as 971f2d23 in phpMyAdmin (type: varbinary(16))`

I want to run a SELECT query like that:

```
$conn->query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE email=971f2d23");
```

but this doesn't return any rows.

I also tried:

```
$conn->query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE email=0x971f2d23");
```

but still no rows.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Enclose the value you are searching for with quotes as in `'0x971f2d23'`.

Comment: that would mean a string "0x971f2d23"  @Dave

Comment: But that should still work/apply with a varbinary column no?

Comment: @Dave See the [hexadecimal literals documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/hexadecimal-literals.html).

Comment: Thanks @tadman ... learn something new every day (which is a good thing).

Comment: The real question is why something labelled `email` is inexplicably a `VARBINARY(16)`. Email addresses can be considerably longer than 16 characters and must be renderable as 7-bit ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$conn->query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE email='971f2d23'");
```